# Annihilation radiation

Tags: particle-physics, photons, standard-model, antimatter

Can photons of microwave wavelengths be emitted from electron-positron annihilation? If not, which processes, preferably other annihilations or particle collisions, produce microwave photons?

Comment: What should annihilate? If you know what annihilates you know the energy and can find the wavelength. look for klystron or magnetron to find out about microwave production.

Comment: Supposing the situation of electron-positron annihilation. How do I find the wavelength?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most [electron-positron annihilations at rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron%E2%80%93positron_annihilation#Low-energy_case) produce two photons, each with 511 keV energy, but [about 0.5%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium#Formation_and_decay_in_materials) of stopped positrons in matter will annihilate via 3-photon [ortho-positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium#States) decays. The ortho-positronium decay photon energy spectrum is [roughly linear](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.hep-ph/0311002) from zero up to the electron mass. i.e.
$$\frac{dN}{dE_\gamma} \sim \frac{2E_\gamma}{m_{electron}^2}$$
[Microwaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave) photons lie roughly in the range from 1µeV to 1meV, so a crude estimate of the average number of microwave photons emitted per stopped positron decay is
$$N_{microwave}\sim 0.5\%\times3\,\mathrm{photons}\times\int_\mathrm{1\,\mu eV}^\mathrm{1\,meV}\frac{2E_\gamma}{m_{electron}^2}dE_\gamma\approx0.03\left(\frac{1\,\mathrm{meV}}{511\,\mathrm{keV}}\right)^2\sim 1\times 10^{-19}\,\mathrm{photons}$$
If I have read Figure 6 in [Manohar & Ruiz-Femenia's paper](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.hep-ph/0311002) correctly, the rate is actually reduced by another factor of 0.3, so we expect a few microwave photons for every $10^{20}$ stopped positron decays.

This is comparable to the [annihilation rate into neutrinos](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9911410), so is not something anyone is likely to observe.

Answer (score 2):

The mass differences for the neutrinos are 10meV and 50meV. Assuming the neutrinos work like the other sets of three generations of particles - their masses geometrically increase. So they should roughly be ~2meV, ~12meV, and ~62meV. So the lightest neutrino we expect to be roughly 2meV. If two of these neutrinos attempt to collide, the cross section for annihilation is unfortunately very small (it's VERY unlikely that this will happen). The photon is the only possible lighter particle they could form, but they don't interact directly with electromagnetism. But there are Feynman diagrams that make the process possible. And it would make two photons of frequency ~500GHz, which I think most people would call microwaves.

Comment: The first group to detect this will get a physics Nobel for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate $mc^2=hf$ for the two emerging photons. The wavelength is much much shorter than microwaves.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to invest in hardware, imagine a relativistic beam of electrons which overtakes a relativistic beam of positrons. Annihilations would produce 511-ish keV photon pairs in the rest frame of the annihilation (plus any extra kinetic energy associated with the particle and antiparticle approaching each other). The radiation would be very strongly boosted in the forward direction, but radiation into the backward direction would be strongly redshifted.  A frequency shift of “only” $10^{9}$ would bring the backwards-going photons down into the micro-eV range of microwaves.

This would be a fabulously inefficient way to make microwaves, and would be perhaps the least interesting use possible of a peta-eV lepton beam.

Answer (score 0):

Annihilation of particles produces photons equal to the rest-mass energy of the particles involved. Only neutrinos may have rest-mass energies in the sub-meV range that could produce microwaves upon annihilation. This is an exceedingly unlikely event.

Microwaves are produced by simple transitions between rotational and vibrational states in molecules. The energy difference between the states frequently corresponds to an emitted microwave photon.

Microwaves are also generated in "free-free" interactions where free electrons are accelerated, typically in the electric field of a nearby positive ion. For terrestrial applications, microwaves can be generated by a celebrating electrons in a [klystron device](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klystron).